# How to assign const static with an incremental macro?

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor, constants, preprocessor-directive

I am trying to assign an unique value to `const static unsigned int` members, without having to think about assigning the right values myself (preventing human errors). I've created a minimal solution for `static unsigned int` members, but I would really like to use `const` instead, because it's faster (and neat).

This is what I came up with:

```
// cat.h
#define ANIMAL_INDEX 0
#define GET_ANIMAL_INDEX (ANIMAL_INDEX (ANIMAL_INDEX + 1))

class Cat
{
protected:
    Cat(){}
public:
    const static unsigned int lynx = GET_ANIMAL_INDEX; // 0
    const static unsigned int tiger = GET_ANIMAL_INDEX; // 1
};
```

This is just an example, but imagine that I would have like 1000 animals or something.

Is it possible to create a macro that increments every time it is used for assignment, or do I need to create a script which generates the `cat.h`?

Comment: This is really what [*enumerations*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) are for.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I want to make a complex enum that is able to do inheritance. A dog.h class would have constants that do not have the same value as the constants in the cat.h class. This way I could call Animal::lynx and Animal::corgi without value conflicts.

Comment: What is the solution you have? It cannot be the code in your question, since that code is erroneous. The requirement i n your comment is important and should be in the question itself.

Comment: What is the purpose of this animal "enumeration"? Why do you need the *values* to be unique? What is the use-case? What is the *original* and *actual* problem you try to solve? ([Related reading about the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).)

Comment: I also think your "speed" requirement is bogus. How do you know it's slow? Have you measured? It's not a case of premature optimization? Keeping it simple, readable and maintainable should be your first priority. If you then profile and find a bottleneck then you can start thinking about possible solutions to that. Remember that hand-made optimizations always make the code more complicated.

Comment: When a base class needs to enumerate its subclasses, you're usually on the wrong track.

Comment: Use _ _ _LINE_ _ _ if there are no any issue originated posiitons of code

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I don't want an alternative, I said in my question I got it working with just the `static` qualifier already. I want to know if it is possible with `static const` simply because I want to and it interest me.

Comment: @molbdnilo please explain why.

Comment: @oddRaven That would require a rather long essay. The shortest version I can come up with is that goes against the principle that a class should be open to extension. If you need to modify the base class in order to inherit from it, it isn't open.

Comment: Usually when beginners want to use enumerations like yours it is because they want to select behavior depending on those enumerations. That goes against the basic principles of polymorphism. What is the reason behind these enumerations? Why can't you have e.g. a `Lynx` subclass of `Cat`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am not a beginner and I am fully aware of enumerations. The reason is inheritance. Some class may only use Cat constants, while some other has only acces to Dog constants, then a third has acces to all of them (Animal constants).

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to move the definitions of your constants outside of their class, then a simple static function based implementation solves your problem:

```
class UniqueIndex 
{
public:
    static int getNext()
    {
        static int theIndex = 0;
        return theIndex++;
    }
};

class Cat
{
protected:
    Cat(){}
public:
    const static unsigned int lynx; 
    const static unsigned int tiger;
};

const unsigned int Cat::lynx = UniqueIndex::getNext();
const unsigned int Cat::tiger = UniqueIndex::getNext();

int main()
{
    std::cout << Cat::lynx << ' ' << Cat::tiger << std::endl; //output: 0 1
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding how questionable a design this might be, an automatic counter can be useful in many cases, so here goes...

Add an abstraction around the "index" and let that handle the counting.
Then your members can be instances of this "indexing type" instead.

Something like this:

```
class Index
{
public:
    Index() : idx(next()) {}
    Index(const Index&) = delete;
    Index& operator=(const Index&) = delete;
    operator int () const { return idx; }
private:
    const int idx;
    // Avoid the "static initialization order fiasco".
    static int next() { static int i = 0; return i++;}
};

struct A
{
    const static Index idx;
};

const Index A::idx;

struct B
{
    const static Index idx;
    const static Index idx2;
};

const Index B::idx;
const Index B::idx2;

int main()
{   
    cout << A::idx << " " << B::idx << " " << B::idx2 << endl;
}
```